# Insufficient Details

Tags: java

there is a project I'm working on , and I've defined a search function that searches through my customer text file , to mention there is a text file called "records",  which new customer details will be stored in after registration defined in the project. so whenever I search for the particular ID , it's working well , but the problem is I want it output rest of the details like his/her name , gender , age . all I have as an output right now is --> "It's Found"
here is the code :

```
    public void searchfile(String input){

    try{

        String details, id, line;
        int count;
        Scanner housenumber = new Scanner(new File("records.txt"));
        while(housenumber.hasNext())
        {
            id = housenumber.next();
            line = housenumber.nextLine();
            if(input.equals(id))
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"It's Found" );
                break;
            }
            if(!housenumber.hasNext())      
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, ID Does Not Exist" );
        }
   }

     catch(IOException e)
   {
     System.out.print("File failure");
   }
};
```

Comment: Who knows. What's the file format? And don't tell me "it is a text file".

Comment: Yeap , it's a text file ....

Comment: Then you need to find a text file expert. They're really expensive. I don't think you can find one that helps you for free.

Comment: If you uploaded a sample of the file you are trying to parse, you would get significantly better answers.

Comment: So what exactly is working and not working so far?  You gotta do the work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty hard answering your question without knowing how the file you are scanning is formatted. If it is formatted something like this:

```
id
name gender age
id
name2 gender age
etc.
```

You could try something like this:

```
id = housenumber.next();
line = housenumber.nextLine();
if(input.equals(id))
{    
    //This should the next line instead of just "It's found"
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,line);

    //Assuming the above file layout, you could then do something like this:
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s+"); //Splits on whitespace

    System.out.println("name: " + parts[0]);
    System.out.println("gender: " + parts[1]);
    System.out.println("age: " + parts[2]);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Dear rusmus , when I add up your code,  the output is blank , I've got no idea how to fix this ,